# Member Area Login with Fail Message

Tags: login, errors

I have a page [here](http://www.novusolutions.com/clients/novusagenda-clients/).

Currently if the member enters the wrong credentials or none at all, they get redirected to the WordPress login screen.

I want instead to have a message appear on the same page... "Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again." ... above or below the form.

I don't know where to start.

Comment: Hi Dan, welcome to WPSE. Please feel free to take the [tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour). We're happy to help here, but as this is a big question it can help to let us know what you've tried already. You said you don't know where to start - have you tried Googling for others who have done this? What did you find and what did you struggle with when implementing those solutions?

Comment: This is not a free coding service. If you really do not know how to do something and also do not know how or what to search for, please hire and pay a developer to code something for you

Comment: Hi Tim, You are right I should have explained. I did google for the answer and found nothing that did exactly what I need, I did find some solutions that were similar, for redirecting the failed login for instance, but my understanding of php is not good enough that I could make it do what I need. I am willing to pay someone to help, and thought I said so in my original post. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to take two scenarios into account because they behave little differently. Copy both of these code blocks to your `functions.php` file. Code about errors is below, make sure to read comments.

---

**1. Login failed - username and password was provided but something was incorrect**

```
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'login_failed_wrong_data' );

function login_failed_wrong_data( $user ) {

    // Get the URL user came from, a.k.a that same login page
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    // Check that we're not on the default login page + other things
    if( ! empty( $referrer ) && ! strstr( $referrer,'wp-login' ) && !strstr( $referrer,'wp-admin' ) && $user != null ) {

        // Check if we don't already have a failed login attempt
        if( ! strstr( $referrer, '?login=failed' ) ) {

            // Redirect to same login page and append a query string
            wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed' );
        } 
        else {

            // Redirect to same login page
            wp_redirect( $referrer );
        }
    }

    exit;
}
```

---

**2. Login failed - username and/or password was not provided at all**

```
add_action( 'authenticate', 'login_failed_no_data' );

function login_failed_no_data( $user ) {

    // Get the URL user came from, a.k.a that same login page
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    $error = false;

    // Check if inputs are empty - these have to match with your input "name" attributes
    if( $_POST['log'] == '' || $_POST['pwd'] == '') {

        $error = true;
    }

    // Check that we're not on the default login page + other things
    if( ! empty( $referrer ) && ! strstr( $referrer,'wp-login' ) && ! strstr( $referrer, 'wp-admin' ) && $error ) {

        // Make sure we don't already have a failed login attempt
        if( ! strstr( $referrer, '?login=failed' ) ) {

            // Redirect to same login page and append a query string
            wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed' );
        } 
        else {

            // Redirect to same login page
            wp_redirect( $referrer );
        }

        exit;
    }   
}
```

---

**Updated error message as shortcode:**

```
// Add this to functions.php
add_shortcode( 'loginerror', 'myErrorShortcode' );

function myErrorShortcode() {

    if( isset( $_GET['login'] ) && $_GET['login'] == 'failed' ) {

        // Start "recording"
        ob_start(); ?>

        <div id="login-error">
            <p>Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again.</p>
        </div> <?php

        // Return result
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}


//How to use
[loginerror]
```

I suggest to do some research and try something yourself next time before asking from community.

Comment: N00b, You are genius! 

It seems to be working, the page is reloading and adding the "?login-failed" to the URL. But I think I need to make the how to show the message part into a shortcode. I have tried to follow this example ... http://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-shortcodes-tutorial/ ... but was unable to make it work.

Ideally the shortcode would work like this [login-error] Message [/login-error]. That way I could place it on the page where ever. I would like to pay you for your trouble just PM me and let me know how I can do that.

Comment: It's not working. I clear the Godaddy Cache, Clear the Cookies and Browser Cache, log out from WordPress, then enter bad credentials, nothing. Even looked in the source code, to see if it's in there - nope. Any ideas? I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Hmm.. That's bizarre. Why do you even need the shortcode? You don't have access to that page's template code? Shortcode should be used only for code that is needed in lots of places (_saves typing, makes life a little bit easier_).

Comment: I am using the Divi theme, so to create a template for that page would force the page to not have the Divi builder functionality. The Divi builder has a Code module for placing shortcodes, on the page. I did create a template file with the first code solution you made and placed your code right inside the #main-content closing div at the bottom. But I did not see the message when doing it that way either.

Comment: I modified it a little bit, try it again. If it still doesn't work, remove `if( isset( $_GET['login'] ) && $_GET['login'] == 'failed' ) {` and corresponding closing parenthesis to see if it will output only the `HTML`.

Comment: No luck. I removed the line as you instructed, and tried again. But I looked carefully at your new code and didn't see a change, could I have missed something?

Comment: I suggest to look into Divi documents and see if you need to register shortcodes following some kind of special instructions. Error can't be in shortcode, it should work. [This](http://divitheme.co.uk/divi-2-4-the-code-modules-for-shortcode-and-html-integration/) maybe?

Comment: Hi N00b, You had it right all along. It was my screw up. I was editing one page and looking at another. Please forgive me, I am an idiot. If I can repay you, let me know how. Thanks! You are da-man! (or da-woman if that's the case).

Comment: Im glad it worked out. You could start with accepting my answer (_checkmark under answer's score_). :-)